# Overwrite Hive table with Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, cloudera

I am trying to modify an existent table in Hive (1.1.0-cdh5.8.2) with Spark (2.2).

If I try to do it directly:

```
val usersTbl = spark.table("db.users").as[Users]
val usersModTbl = usersTbl.withSomeModifications
usersModTbl.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("db.users")
```

It fails with an error:

> Cannot overwrite table db.users that is also being read from.

After some search, I have reached an intermediate solution, consistent on write to a temporal table, and after that, move it to the original one:

```
usersModTbl.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("parquet").saveAsTable("db.temp_table")
val tempTbl = spark.table("db.temp_table")
tempTbl.show
tempTbl.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("db.users")
```

It seems to work, but in the end, the table temp_table contains the information correctly but the db.users table it is always **empty**. Also the tempTbl.show shows an empty table..., but when the Job finishes the temp_table contains the information.

Thank you very much,

Javi.